# Javascript Shorthanding

Tags: javascript

Consider the following example:

```
if (cache) {
    x = cache;
} else {
    x = cache = someMethod();
}
```

Anyway to make this shorter than `cache ? x = cache : x = cache = someMethod();`?

**EDIT:**

Thanks for all the proposed solutions, I should have noted that the data in question is strings not booleans.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
x = cache || (cache = someMethod());
```

Comment: or x = cache = cache || someMethod()

Comment: @Qnan Nice, you save two parentheses, but you always make an assignmet for `cache`, even if it's truthy. Oh, well...

Comment: Nice, conditional assignment. One question: So does the `cache = someMethod()` statement _return_ the value of `someMethod()`?

Comment: If cache was never assigned, this would throw a `ReferenceError`

Comment: @KooiInc I think it's safe to assume that it was already assigned, given what Kay wrote.

Comment: @MaxArt: in programming nothing is *safe to assume*, so I provided an amendment ;-)

Comment: @KooiInc You amendment looks good and I upvoted it. But you, on the other hand, are *assuming* that Kay isn't aware of that. Kay asked a very precise and simple question, so answering to allegedly related issues just unnecessarily complicates things.

Comment: @MaxArt: well, answers may be of use to *anyone* interested, so I'm not assuming Kay isn't aware of it, but more generally like to point out a possible misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

If it's not sure `cache` is declared and/or assigned before, this is an amendment to [MaxArt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/714240/maxart)s answer (using [short circuit boolean evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) and the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/Comma_Operator)):

```
x = (cache = window.cache || someMethod(),cache);
//note: 'window' may be another namespace
```

In strict mode that wouldn't work either. In that case this would:

```
'use strict';
var x = function(w){w.cache = w.cache || someMethod(); return w.cache;}(window);
```

Comment: I think a "real" amendment would be `x = window.cache || (cache = someMethod())`, this looks like a different approach. Anyway, both fail in strict mode if `cache` wasn't declared.

Comment: Yep, ECMAscript is very flexible, so there are often alternatives. Added a `strict mode` solution to the answer, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

The clean way to do this (working even with bools) would be

```
   if (cache === undefined) { cache = someMethod (); }
   x = cache;
```

Comment: What's wrong with `if (!cache) {...}` rather than `if (cache === undefined) {...}`?

Comment: If Kay is ok with `if (cache)` I think it's ok not to change it. Maybe  wants the condition to be true even if `cache` is `0` or `false` or `null`...

Comment: If the result of `someMethod` is a boolean value or an number that might be zero or the string "", `!cache` does not determine whether cache is set or not.

Comment: @JohnB Does it matter? You don't know if Kay actually wants to know if `cache` is set or not.

Comment: No, I don't. But it's the only reason which makes sense to me.

Comment: Doesn't work if they actively want to replace a `cache` set to null (common) or false or zero (less likely in good real code, but possible).

Comment: Or even if they actively want to replace a cache set to 3498098.